Complex Conjugation
I have an expression of the form,
\begin{equation}
e^{i\frac{2\pi}{L}\hat{X}} |\psi_0\rangle \approx e^{i \gamma_L} \left(|\psi_0\rangle -   \frac{2\pi \hbar}{mL}   \sum_{j\neq 0} |\psi_j\rangle \frac{\langle \psi_j |\hat{P}| \psi_0\rangle}{E_0 -E_j} \right)        \tag1
\end{equation}
$\hat{P} $ is the momentum operator.
Its Complex conjugate will be,
$$\langle \psi_o |e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{L}\hat{X}}  \approx e^{-i \gamma_L} \left(\langle \psi_o |-   \frac{2\pi \hbar}{mL}   \sum_{j\neq 0}  \frac{\langle \psi_0|\hat{P}| \psi_j\rangle}{E_0 -E_j} \langle \psi_j|\right)  \tag2$$
Now i have,
$$\frac{d}{dt} \langle X \rangle = \frac{L}{2\pi} \text{Im} \left(\frac{\langle \dot{\psi_0} |e^{i\frac{2\pi}{L}\hat{X}} |\psi_0\rangle}{\langle {\psi_0} |e^{i\frac{2\pi}{L}\hat{X}} |\psi_0\rangle}  + \frac{\langle {\psi_0} |e^{i\frac{2\pi}{L}\hat{X}} |\dot{\psi_0}\rangle}{\langle {\psi_0} |e^{i\frac{2\pi}{L}\hat{X}} |\psi_0\rangle}\right)  \tag3$$
I am trying to get the following equation by using the equation 1 and 2 in 3,
$$\frac{d}{dt} \langle X \rangle \approx \frac{i \hbar}{m} \sum_{j\neq0} \langle \dot{\psi_0}|\psi_j\rangle \frac{\langle \psi_j |\hat{P}| \psi_0\rangle}{E_0 -E_j} + c.c.  \tag4$$
Where c.c. indicates the complex conjugate.
I tried substituting 1 and 2 in 3 to get the final result but I am confused about how can I make the substitution of equation 2 in the 2nd term of equation 3, since it does not have any negative sign in the exponential (which is in the numerator). I am also confused if I have written equation 2 correctly!
Any help will be appreciated!

In equation 2, why do you have $+{2\pi\hbar\over mL}$ instead of $-{2\pi\hbar\over mL}$? I thought you should not have this plus sign, since the expression 2 is just complex conjugation of 1

@Ruffolo It was a typo, sorry for the mistake!
